# Install MySQL NDB cluster on CentOS. What version use?

Tags: linux, centos, yum

I am new in Linux.
I need for test purpose install NDB Mysql cluser.
Read a lot of documentation and How to do.
As a result  I am not understand. For example
https://featout.com/the-complete-guide-mysql-cluster-on-centos-7/
It has instruction for example

```
wget http://cdn.mysql.com//Downloads/MySQL-Cluster-7.6/mysql-cluster-community-**7.6.15-1.el7.x86_64**.rpm-bundle.tar
tar -xvf mysql-cluster-community-7.6.15-1.el7.x86_64.rpm-bundle.tar
```

I have question why instruction have version of Mysql mysql-cluster-community-7.6.15-1.el7.x86_64.rpm-bundle.tar. Document can wrote  many years ago. How can i find most suitable  and up to date version for my  CentOS.
How can i find version according my version of OS or may be it is not important?
Thank  you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official doc tells about it is very recommended to use last update version of software. To do this need to add additional repository
of mysql, because standard repository does not contain it.

Some documentation, which is use some version of software without explanation about that you need to find new and how to do it, for starter of linux not clear.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).